# Конвертация string в char*

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("1.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      system (line);
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";

  return 0;
}
```

Получаю

> main.cpp:14: ошибка: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int system(const char*)'
>          system (line);
>                      ^

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сконвертировать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Очень просто - `system(line.c_str());`

Comment: к сожалению всё равно не компилится

main.cpp:14: ошибка: invalid use of non-static member function
       system (line.c_str);
                         ^

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно, как стоят скобки у меня и как их поставили вы